# Using Pivot to change Rows into Columns

Tags: sql, pivot, pivot-table

I am resposting this and adding additional information. I am working on a SQL Query and using Pivot and running into an issue. The columns which I have in the Pivot Table actually show as row data and is repeated for each server.

```
WITH agg AS 
   (
    select NodeID, 
           count(distinct cpuindex) as number_of_cpu, 
           case 
               when count(distinct cpuindex) < 8 THEN 1
               else count(distinct cpuindex) / 8 
           end AS number_of_cores
    from CPUMultiLoad_Detail 
    where nodeid in (select nodeid from nodesdata)
    group by NodeID
   )
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT cp.Environment, n.Caption,
       cs.ComponentName,cs.ComponentStatisticData, cs.ErrorMessage,
       agg.NodeID, agg.number_of_cpu, agg.number_of_cores, n.description
FROM APM_CurrentStatistics cs 
INNER JOIN APM_Application app 
  ON cs.ApplicationID = app.ID
  AND app.Name IN ('Oracle Database Licensing') 
INNER JOIN NodesData n
  ON cs.NodeID = n.NodeID
  AND n.description NOT LIKE '%Windows%'
INNER JOIN NodesCustomProperties cp 
  ON cp.NodeID = n.NodeID
INNER JOIN agg
  ON cs.NodeID = agg.NodeID
) t
PIVOT(
   max(cs.ErrorMessage) FOR cs.ComponentName IN (
        [Oracle Version], 
        [Oracle Partitioning],
        [Oracle Tuning Pack], 
        [Diagnostic Pack], 
        [Real Application Clusters (RAC)]) 
) AS pivot_table;
```

Desired Output

[image]

I am getting this Error
Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
The column prefix 'cs' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.
Msg 107, Level 15, State 1, Line 30
The column prefix 'cs' does not match with a table name or alias name used in the query.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What database are you using ? any sample data or DDL commands will help. Looks like You need max(ErrorMessage) FOR ComponentName as the scope of cs is only until the main query aliased as table t is not created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take out the two `cs.` in this line

```
max(cs.ErrorMessage) FOR cs.ComponentName IN (
```

It treats the prior select statement like it has already run so those column names don't need to be disambiguated

Comment: Thank you so much Hogan. You really made my day.

Comment: sure @SQLNovice -- wellcome to SO.  Remember to mark this question as answered by clicking on the check mark to the left of this answer (or whichever answer answers your question).  This will help the site run better.